# Writing stories for SAP

Tags: scrum, agile, agile-coach

*Perhaps this will get criticised for being technical, but SO seems the wrong place for it.*

If you are running/involved in a project with SAP developers, how do you/they write stories for it? What do the stories usually look like?

To be specific, I'm (not an SAP developer but I am...) referring to technical stories which specify changes/additions to web services provided by SAP to client applications.

Our team tend to write good stories, but when the SAP technical stories get written it turns into the legacy style of writing stories and, more often than note, is a dump of the knowledge the person writing the story has with notes to say "change this." It's not digestible by anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

> As a user of the reporting service
>
> when fetching the latest Klausen statistics
>
> I also want to get the average Neuman-sum over all averages I obtained
>
> so I don't have to implement that algorithm myself and I can be sure all departments use the same numbers

There is no reason that the "user" cannot be another program, for example the reporting frontend that another team provides. You could then dump the technical details into a "details" part of the story, so the knowledge does not get lost.